# How to php check when Paypal subscription ends?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I know there are tons of docs about php paypal subscriptions and I am flooded with all these docs.

Does someone has a simple php snippet for paypal subscriptions including signinig up and canceling ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

just use ready lib ([paypal-digital-goods](https://github.com/thenbrent/paypal-digital-goods))

there is a demo and very easy manual to use it

you do not need to write a new stuff

Comment: Thanks...
 $paypal_subscription = new PayPal_Subscription( $subscription_details ); 
How do I process the subscription cancelling ?

Comment: come on man, just see the examples https://github.com/thenbrent/paypal-digital-goods-php-examples/

Comment: I did : but I don't know where you define the path to cancel.php when someone cancels his subscription from Paypal console.